# Django. Serving staticfiles with DEBUG=false on local

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/apis/icons/random-svgrepo-com.svg` gives me error 404 not found.

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/'),
]
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media')
```

**template.html**

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'apis/icons/random-svg.svg' %}">
```

**root urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Work directory:

[image]

I am running `./manage.py collectstatic`, and then run the server. But it doesn't show me my image.

My questions are:

1. Difference between `STATICFILES_DIR` and `STATICFILES_DIRS`
2. What I am doing wrong? Why my static files doesn't appear to work fine?

Thanks!

Comment: `in production on local` what do you mean by this? `in production` = `debug = false`? _in production_ usually means somewhere else than _local_, on some remote server.

Comment: question 1 - there is only one thing https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: @IvanStarostin, DEBUG is set to False, but its on my local computer.

Comment: Yeah, totally :( But not the accepted answer, but what is under it. I changed my root urls.py to ```urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT})
]
```. I ll post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Changed my root urls.py to:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT})
]
```